# How can I make Docker trigger higher CPU frequencies

Tags: docker, windows-10, cpu-usage

OK, so my title may not actually be linked to a possible solution, however this is my problem.
I am running a Python 3 Jupyter notebook inside a docker container in from my windows 10 kaby-lake (2 physical cores, 4 virtual cores) laptop.
I noticed while doing heavy computing from there, my CPU usage seen in the task monitor is very low (~15%).
When going on the details for each process, the VBoxHeadless.exe actually uses 24% of the processor, which matches `docker stats` command which yields 97-100% CPU usage, and therefore makes sense from a single-core operation point of view.
[image: Result of docker stats]
[image: CPU usage of Docker/VBoxHeadless]
My actual issue is that even though on thread is filled in terms of CPU time, windows (I guess) does not decide that it may actually be useful to speed up the CPU, and therefore it runs at 1.7GHz (with other apps in high performance mode, I usually hit the max 3.5GHz that the computer is capable of).
[image: CPU monitor]
Therefore, how can I induce the higher clock speeds (nominal 2.7GHz or max 3.5GHZ) (considering that they would probably double my single threaded speed) from docker itself or inside windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the docker machine running docker. If you haven't created a custom one, the default docker machine named 'default' will only have access to one cpu.

You can check all the configuration for this docker-machine by running:

```
docker-machine inspect default
```

You need to purge this default machine and recreate it:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "400000" --virtualbox-cpu-count "2" --virtualbox-memory "2048" default
```

You can check all the avaible configuration options for the machine by running:

```
docker-machine create --help
```

Comment: I did all this, and now my default docker machine has potentially twice as much memory and twice as many cores to use from, but actually that's not what I was referring to (speed has not changed). I'm actually talking about single core performance with higher CPU frequencies

Answer (score 0):

Defining CPU Shares can help you but not exactly.

CPU limits are based on shares as these shares are a weight between how much processing time one process should get compared to another. If a CPU is idle, then the process will use all the available resources. If a second process requires the CPU then the available CPU time will be shared based on the weighting.
e.g. The `--cpu-shares` parameter defines a share between 0-768. If a container defines a share of 768, while another defines a share of 256, the first container will have 50% share while the other one having 25% of the available share total.

Below the first container will be allowed to have 75% of the share. The second container will be limited to 25%.

```
docker run -d --name p1 --cpuset-cpus 0 --cpu-shares 768 image_name
docker run -d --name p2 --cpuset-cpus 0 --cpu-shares 256 image_name
sleep 5
docker stats --no-stream
docker rm -f p1 p2
```

It's important to note that a process can have 100% of the share, no matter defined weight, if no other processes are running.

Comment: Tried this as well, but did not affect the overall request for more cpu on windows level, I think the issue is more window 10 related.